# Set different length to String in different lines of TextView

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, textview

I'm making a list of news. Each element could be 1-3 lines height. 
Also, there must be a date in the right, text should end before it, but at the 2nd line text should be under date text, and in the end, if text is too long, it should end with "...", but (!) last word (name of news company) must stay as it is. Header of news could be any lenght and it must be white, text of news also could be any length and must be gray.  If the headline goes over more than one line, then the main text can begin right
after the headline in the same line.

What i already know:
For "..." at the end of the text i want to use `android:ellipsize="end"`, for different coloring of text `SpannableString` and `ForegroundColorSpan`.

What i need: how to make text in one TextView that would have different length of each line and would cut text before last word. Maybe it's possible using multiple TextView's, i'm not sure, cause header could be on 1 line or on 2 lines.

Example of what i need at the end.

```
Header header header header DATE
header Text text text text text text
text text text text text text...Name
```

Thank you for any answers and advices.

Comment: Yes it possible to do with several `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Make you text as html text, break it using html tag and set that text to textview using `Html.fromhtml(htmltext);`